# Find the similarity scores between sentences

Tags: python, deep-learning, nlp

I am trying to find the similar sentences from my data and my code gives me an output that basically ranks the similar sentences like RANK 1, 2 and 3 where Rank 1 will be the highly similar sentence. I used BM25 to find this out
For example: Sentence 1: "The person is wearing a red-shirt

Rank 1 : "the boy is wearing a red shirt"

Rank 2 : "the boy is wearing a shirt"

Rank 3 : "the girl is wearing a dress"

I would also want to know the similarity score to find out how similar the sentences are. Would need help there!

Comment: You might want to look into the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) to assess the similarity. It's implemented in [fuzzywuzzy](https://pypi.org/project/fuzzywuzzy/) in Python.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `SequenceMatcher` from `difflib`

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
s = SequenceMatcher(None, "the boy is wearing a red shirt", "the boy is wearing a shirt")
print(s.ratio())
```

**Output**

```
0.9285714285714286 # 1 being max
```

**Or**

You can use [thefuzz](https://pypi.org/project/thefuzz/) library

```
fuzz.ratio("the boy is wearing a red shirt", "the boy is wearing a shirt") # 100 being max
```

**Or**

You can use [jellyfish](https://pypi.org/project/jellyfish/) library

```
import jellyfish
jellyfish.levenshtein_distance(u'jellyfish', u'smellyfish') # 2

jellyfish.jaro_distance(u'jellyfish', u'smellyfish') # 0.89629629629629

jellyfish.damerau_levenshtein_distance(u'jellyfish', u'jellyfihs') # 1
```

You can find most of the text similarity methods and how they are calculated under this link: https://github.com/luozhouyang/python-string-similarity#python-string-similarity

Comment: What would be the treshold where you would say the 2 sentences are similar? 0.5%?